# Giving different names to a struct with same body

Tags: c, struct

I have a code duplication situation where I have exact same body of struct but with different names. The body of struct is not small, hence there is risk of injecting error while modifying code in future. Following is just example to illustrate the problem:

```
struct read_data_on_disk {
    int a;
    char b;
};
struct read_data {
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

It is possible to define one of them, say read_data_on_disk and another be just defined as alias of it? I am looking for something like below:

```
typedef struct read_data_on_disk struct read_data; // this is wrong though
```

Comment: If the two structs will always be exactly the same other than the struct name, why have two structs?

Comment: Use `typedef struct read_data_on_disk read_data`. Remove the last `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

That's almost right. Try this:

```
struct read_data_on_disk {
    int a;
    char b;
};

typedef struct read_data_on_disk read_data;
```

But as dbush pointed out above, why have two structs if their content is identical?